# Is there any relation between VMWare VMotion and VMFS?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, vsphere

I was studying VMWare's VSphere suite, cloud computing virtualization platform.

I could not figure out whether there's any relation between VMotion and VMFS in the suite?

VMotion enables the live migration of running virtual machines from
one physical server to another with zero down time.

VMFS is a clustered file system that leverages shared storage to allow multiple physical hosts to read and write to the same storage simultaneously.

Is there any relation between them?

Comment: This is a question better directed at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 2):

No.

As you mention, VMFS is the file system we use by default on "block" shared storage (i.e. LUNs).  This allows us to have the same LUN mounted for read/write on multiple ESXi hosts which is not allowed with many file systems.

vMotion is when we move a running VM from one ESXi host to another.  We do this by copying the running memory state from one host to another.  When then "stun" the VM for a short period of time and quickly move it's virtual NIC to the new server.  The VM "starts" on the far side in the same state, thus it appears like the VM has always been running.  That is to say we "move" the running VM even though we are actually just creating a new VM with exactly the same memory state and disk.

The only relationship is that if you have a VM whose VMDKs live in a Datastore which is shared across multiple ESXi hosts, the vMotion process doesn't have to copy the VMDK which makes the process much simpler and faster.  Since VMFS is one way we can support shared storage, it is common to have VMDK's on VMFS based datastores (in this case 1 datastore = one VMFS formatted LUN).  Since VMFS is our oldest shared storage technology, it's the most common and usually be best understood by our customers.

However, any shared storage will work just fine for vMotion, including VSAN, VVOL and NFS based shared storage.